# Why is the current flowing into the power supply?

Tags: current, inverter, pmos

I tried to make a latch , and observed that there was current flowing through the PMOS into Vdd for some time duration. But then during that time the voltage across the drain is less than Vdd. Can someone tell me how this is even possible ?

I have attached the graph and the circuit with the question. Please let me know if I need to provide more info.
[image: how can Is(M6) be negative?]

[image: CIRCUIT]

Comment: Looks like parasitic MOSFET capacitance is the answer and although it seems like it's flowing into the supply, it won't be. It's probably circulating in M6 through the bulk connection.

Comment: Can you suggest a material from which I can calculate the exact value of these intresnsic capacitance ? I wanted to find the exact power consumption and for that I need to find the capacitance Cx,Cy,Cp and Cq. I know that it will be some of few Cgs ,Cgd etc. But then how will I find the exact values for that ?  @Andyaka

Comment: I can't suggest material for this.

Comment: Okay, will it be possible to calculate the exact values of parasitic capacitance? I have the dimensions of the transistors and I am using level 49 , 180nm technology. With these information , I wanted to know those values. I guess this is possible but I am not sure with the equations.

Comment: There is no such thing as an exact value when it comes to MOSFETs - they are all voltage dependent.

Comment: Oh, did you mean Vdd when you said voltage ? @Andyaka

Comment: No, I didn't. Is this going anywhere. You have your answer and you've accepted it and there is no issue so, what's your lingering problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126940/discussion-between-hari-krishna-and-andy-aka).

Comment: In a word, no... this is not going anywhere.

Comment: I am extremely sorry if you feel I was wasting your time. But then I was just trying to quantify the intrinsic capacitance so that I can compare the power consumption due to dynamic as well as direct path current.  @Andyaka

Comment: Just look how power develops vs toggling frequency and you reveal static and dynamic powers.

Comment: dissipation due to capacitive charging and discharging , I wanted to theoretically calculate it and check it with the simulation value. For that we know  CV^2 will be the energy dissipated. Thats why I was checking a method to calculate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that this current flowing back into the supply flows only for a fraction of a nano-second!

What happens is easier to explain with a much simpler circuit like a CMOS inverter. In your latch the same situation will occur when the latch changes state.

I have drawn 3 inverter circuits. The left circuit is a standard inverter, nothing new.

The middle circuit is the same inverter but I have added a capacitor in parallel with the Gate-Source of the PMOS. This capacitor represents the \$C_{GS}\$ inside the PMOS. I have also indicated the voltages at the gate and source of the PMOS when the input (source V_LOW) is low, so 0 V.

The 3rd circuit on the right shows the same (middle) circuit again but now the input source (V_HIGH) has just become **high** so 3 V (assume Vdd = 3 V as well). Now pay attention to the top plate of the capacitor \$C_{GS3}\$, note that it is at 6 V! How can that be? That's higher than the supply voltage!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwT7l4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Look back to the circuit in the middle and see how we charged \$C_{GS2}\$ to 3 V. Then in circuit number 3 we raised the voltage at the bottom plate of the capacitor (the gate of the PMOS) to 3 V, since the capacitor is still charged to 3 V that means the top plate of the capacitor (the source of the PMOS) will be lifted to 6 V.

But the supply is 3 V! Yes so that capacitor \$C_{GS2}\$ will now **discharge** through the supply and that is the current that you're seeing flowing back into the supply.

Since the current is quite small and the duration of the current is very short, this is not really an issue. In CMOS logic circuits we only need to add sufficient **supply decoupling capacitors** which will then absorb this small current.

Comment: We can observe that V(y) and V(x) are going above 1.8V (Vdd in my circuit.). In that latch the S1,S2,S3 and S4 pre charge the points to Vdd . But right after the CK turns HIGH(1ns) the values jumps slightly above 1.8V. Is it safe to say that this is also possible to due to coupling of capacitor (similar to the -ve current)? In this case which intrinsic capacitor causes this? Cgs of M2 or Cgd of S1?

Comment: also this is the direct path current through one inverter , so I wanted to find the total energy dissipated due to direct path current. Will it be safe to approximate it as two triangles and subtract the area of the inverted triangle?  @Bimpelrekkie

Comment: *Is it safe to say that this is also possible to due to coupling of capacitor* You're in a simulator so you can do whatever you like! So just add an ideal capacitor (in parallel with gate-source) in your circuit like in my schematics and see what happens. *Will it be safe to approximate* As a first order approximation, that should be good enough. But you're in a simulator so you can just plot the supply current and then you can determine power dissipation as well.

Comment: I plotted the supply current (Is(M6)). The current is negative for a short duration , so can I subtract that small triangle from the bigger(due to positive current) while calculating the total energy dissipated ?